# Out of Memory error in Netflix zuul (AWS) even I gave 6 GB -Xmx

Tags: java, spring-boot, out-of-memory, netflix-zuul, heap-size

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YddVi.png)

[image]

I have added -Xmx to 6GB but still I am getting this error. When I am trying to upload a large file in Springboot application via Zuul. I can able to upload upto 600 MB file. I need to make it 4 GB.

Comment: I think case is important. If so, it's `-Xmx` (instead of `-XMx`), e.g. `-Xmx6g`.

Comment: I gave with the exact case only. I am just mentioned smaller case here. Sorry for that